# Ruby On Rails: upload a file to a specific folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I am using this [file uploader example for Ruby on Rail](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example).

Now the files are saved by their IDs into: `public->system->uploads->uploads->000->000.`

I need it to be saved into such system of folders: `public->system->Files->Types(JPG OR PDF)`
The files have to be saved not according to their IDs but according to their types.

Example:

All jpg files should be saved into:
`public->system->Files->JPG`

All PDF files should be saved into:
`public->system->Files->PDF`

I have already created the folders, I need only to specify a path where the files have to be saved.

That is a code from `uploads_controller.rb`

```
 def create
    p_attr=params[:upload]
    p_attr[:upload] = params[:upload][:upload].first if params[:upload][:upload].class == Array
    @upload = Upload.new(p_attr)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @upload.save
        format.html {
          render :json => [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json,
          :content_type => 'text/html',
          :layout => false
        }

        format.json { render json: [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json, status: :created, location: @upload }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }


        format.json{ render json: {name:(@upload.upload_file_name).split(".").first ,error: @upload.errors.messages[:upload_file_name]}, :status =>422}

      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend switching to [carrierwave uploader](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave). There are config options , which are going to help you in separating files by type . I mean , in this configuration in carrierwave uploader :

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{Rails.env}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"    
end
```

you can alter the 'model.id' part with a method , naming the image by type .

Comment: I would not like to switch. If there is a possibility to do it with paperclip, I would like to know it.

Comment: Unfortunately , I've got no experience with paperclip .

Answer (score 0):

You can manually do this using regex. So it'd be something like:

```
type = p_attr.filename.match(/^*\w{3,}$/).to_s
```

filename being whatever its called within p_attr. So that would give you the file type ending as a string. According to the paperclip gem you can set a different path and url by setting them as a param:

```
path = "#{Rails.env}/public/system/FILE/#{type}"
@upload = Upload.new(p.attrs, path: path, url: path)
```

Not 100% sure on the upload line, but something like that should be able to override the paperclip default.

For more information check the [paperclip readme](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage) section about storage. It explains about overriding default path.

Answer (score 0):

[Changing Paperclip File Storage Location](http://travisonrails.com/2009/01/11/changing-paperclip-file-storage-location)